# write a function finding maximum/minimum of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, max

[WITHOUT USING MIN/MATH Function]

The question ask me to create the function including 2 parameters.first is an array and the second parameter is either the String “`Minimum`” or “`Maximum`” . It confusing me when i don't know how to input the parameter as the string in the function. So that i decide to create 2 similar function as `extremeValue(vector, maximum)` and `extremeValue(vector, minimum)` ( I still don't know whether i can do that or not ). 
And this is my code for `extremeValue(vector, maximum)`.

So the way i did is create the array which have the same value with `vector[i]` than i using if statement to see if it bigger than that vector or not. However, The code is doesn't work. :(

```
var vector = [3, 1, 1]
var maximum

//------------this function give us the vector with all same value---------------//
function set(value, len) {

    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr.push(value);
    }
    return arr;
}
//---------------------------------------------------//


//---------------------------------------------------//
function extremeValue(vector, maximum) {
    var answer = "";

    for (var count = 1; count++; count < vector.length) {
        if (set(vector[count], vector.length) > vector)
            answer += vector[count] + "is maximum"
    }
    return answer
}

//---------------------------------------------------//
console.log(extremeValue(vector, maximum))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using `Math` or any other javascript function, you can find the `max` and `min` values of an array as below.

```js
var arr = [2, 3, 5, 10, 2, -9, 3];

alert("Max value is " + arrayMaxMin(arr, "Max"));
alert("Min value is " + arrayMaxMin(arr, "Min"));

function arrayMaxMin(array, selector) {

  var val = array[0];   // variable to hold the current max/min value.

  for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (selector == "Min") {
      if (array[i] < val) {
        val = array[i];
      }
    } else if (selector == "Max") {
      if (array[i] > val) {
        val = array[i];
      }
    }

  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Hi. they does not allow us use min max function :(

Comment: @TimNguyen I have updated the answer to make it work without using `Math` functions :)

Comment: `arrayMaxMin([10,1,12], "Min")` won't work. Your example works only because you have negative number in it.  `1 < ''` will return false. You can change your answer to `var val = array[0]` and `for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {`

Comment: Also `val = arr[i];` should be to `val = array[i]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Math` functions. [**Math.min**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) will return you the smallest number of the passed numbers. You cannot call these functions directly on array so, you can use `apply` to call these functions and pass the `array` as parameters to the functions.

> The `Math.min()` function returns the smallest of zero or more numbers.

`Math.max`  as follow:

```js
// array: The source array
// type: 'max' or 'min' to find Maximum or Minimum number
var getNum = function(array, type) {
  return Math[type].apply(null, array);
};

var arr = [1, 3, 35, 12];
document.write('Max: ' + getNum(arr, 'max'));

document.write('<br />Min: ' + getNum(arr, 'min'));
```

**UPDATE**

> they does not allow us use min max function

You can use array methods to get maximum and minimum value. Sort the array in ascending order and then the first element in array will be minimum and last element is maximum.

```js
// array: Source array
// type: 'max' or 'min'
var getNum = function(array, type) {

  // Sort the array by ascending order
  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a < b;
  });

  return type === 'max' ? array[0] : array[array.length - 1];
};

var vector = [233, 10, 32543, 54321];

var max = getNum(vector, 'max');
var min = getNum(vector, 'min');

document.write('Max: ' + max);
document.write('<br />Min: ' + min);
```

Comment: Hi. they does not allow us use min max function :(

Answer (score 3):

This should work too!. Hope it helps bro.

```
 var arr = [2 ,4 ,56, 23, 10];
 var max = arr.reduce(function(x,y){
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
 });
 var min = arr.reduce(function(x,y){
    return (x < y) ? x : y;
 });
 console.log('Max: '+ max);
 console.log('Min: '+ min);
```

Comment: MAX is not a constant so you need to use max as your naming convention?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
function extremeValue(my_arr, min_max) {
  var retval, i, len;
  for(i=0,len=my_arr.length; i < len; i++) {
     if (min_max == 'minimum') {
       retval = (my_arr[i] < retval ? my_arr[i] : retval);
     } else {
       retval = (my_arr[i] > retval ? my_arr[i] : retval);
     }
  }
  return retval;
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
console.log(extremeValue(vector, 'maximum'));
console.log(extremeValue(vector, 'minimum'));
```

Comment: Hi. they does not allow us use min max function :(

Comment: I didn't use `Math.min()` or `Math.max()`.

Answer (score 0):

Without the Built in Math Min/Max method:

```js
let minMaxValues = (arr) => {
    let maxValues;
    let minValues;
 
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      // check first value with all iterater
      if(arr[i] < arr[1]){
        minValues = arr[i];
      }

      // check last value with all iterater
      if(arr[i] > arr[arr.length-1]){
        maxValues = arr[i];
      }
      
    }
    console.log(minValues);
    console.log(maxValues);
  }

  minMaxValues([100, 20, 30, 10, 50]);
```